# Is there any way to let the data range of a chart in Google Sheets dynamically adjust?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Say I have a table like this:

```
| Date  | Number |
| 0128  | 28800  | 
| 0129  | 32500  | 
| 0130  | 63410  | 
| 0131  | 56400  | 
| 0201  | 68700  | 
| 0202  | 84060  |
```

And I can put a graph to show the data.

However, what if I add a new row to the end, I have to re-assign the range of the graph's data to make it redraw.

Is there any way that I can let the graph "know" that I have added a new row?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, unless you extend the range. All you need to do is include a bigger range then your data sits on. In your example, your dataset is on the range **A1:B7**. After you create a chart/graph from this range then click to edit this range and remove the last number so it would be **A1:B** and click on **<kbd>OK</kbd>** button. This way will chart/graph account for every newly added row in range calculated by chart/graph after you clicked on **<kbd>OK</kbd>** button.

[image: 0]